# Why is :first-child not working?

Tags: jquery, html, css, radio-button, css-selectors

Why is this portion of jQuery not working properly?

```
$(function() {

  if ($('#slide-01').is(":first-child")) {
    $('input:radio[id=target-slide-01]').prop('checked', true);
  } else {
    $('input:radio[id=target-slide-01]').prop('checked', false);
  }

  if ($('#slide-02').is(":first-child")) {
    $('input:radio[id=target-slide-02]').prop('checked', true);
  } else {
    $('input:radio[id=target-slide-02]').prop('checked', false);
  }

  if ($('#slide-03').is(":first-child")) {
    $('input:radio[id=target-slide-03]').prop('checked', true);
  } else {
    $('input:radio[id=target-slide-03]').prop('checked', false);
  }

  if ($('#slide-04').is(":first-child")) {
    $('input:radio[id=target-slide-04]').prop('checked', true);
  } else {
    $('input:radio[id=target-slide-04]').prop('checked', false);
  }

});
```

The link to where the jQuery is being implemented is located on this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwierzba/osxjecch/).

When I inspect the elements within the HTML and CSS, each slide eventually has the ':first-child' (as the slides rotate), but my guess is the jQuery is not recognizing the rotation or my jQuery is off somewhere.

I have also tried using :first in place of :first-child, but it does not make a difference.

Comment: I don't know jQuery, but if you are going to start out with markup that has four slides, then slide three will logically never be a first-child, no?

Comment: You just call the function once the DOM is ready but nevermore ... then the first-child is always slide-01 . You need to call the function everytime you change the slide.

Comment: @Danko: you should add it as an answer :)

Comment: @Danko How would I go about calling the function, with the "first" slide being inserted after the "last" slide every 6 seconds? Would I need to be using .change() or something along those lines? I am fairly new with jQuery, so I apologize in advance.

Comment: you could give this function a name, and then call it inside your intervall function... but looking at your code, i'd suggest, you tell us, what you really want to achieve ... cause it looks, like you're doing things more complicated, than needed...

Comment: @errand I am really just trying to have it where if a slide is being displayed (becomes "first-child"), then the corresponding label/radio becomes checked. This way the bottom navigation shows the selected slide and scrolls with it's corresponding slide. Again, I am fairly new with jQuery so if there is anything I can do better, I appreciate the critique. :)

Comment: the provided solution may work. i won't post the following as an answer, since it's no answer to your question, but some suggestions to your code: inside your click function  $(selection).click(function() you can address the actual clicked element with $(this). if your selects and your target slides, are always the same amount, you can work with the .index() function to change through the slides and the selects! this should make your resorting obsolete. running out of characters... can't get more specific inside a comment, sry...

Comment: @errand Thank you for the suggestions! I will definitely be using your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function for your radiobuttons only get's called once on page loading since it's an anonymous self invoking function. If you give a name

```
function updateRadioButtons() {

    if ($('#slide-01').is(":first-child")) {
      $('input:radio[id=target-slide-01]').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $('input:radio[id=target-slide-01]').prop('checked', false);
    }

    if ($('#slide-02').is(":first-child")) {
      $('input:radio[id=target-slide-02]').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $('input:radio[id=target-slide-02]').prop('checked', false);
    }

    if ($('#slide-03').is(":first-child")) {
      $('input:radio[id=target-slide-03]').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $('input:radio[id=target-slide-03]').prop('checked', false);
    }

    if ($('#slide-04').is(":first-child")) {
      $('input:radio[id=target-slide-04]').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $('input:radio[id=target-slide-04]').prop('checked', false);
    }

  }
```

you can call it when your slides got changed

```
function moveLeft() {
    $('#myslider ul').animate({
        left: +containerWidth
    }, 600, function () {
        $('#myslider ul > li:last-child').insertBefore('#myslider ul > li:first-child');
        $(this).css('left', '');
        updateRadioButtons();
    });

}

function moveRight() {
    $('#myslider ul').animate({
        left: -containerWidth
    }, 600, function () {
      $('#myslider ul > li:first-child').insertAfter('#myslider ul > li:last-child');
      $(this).css('left', '');
        updateRadioButtons();
    });

}
```

and also on page loading

```
$(function() {

  // Key animation.

    updateRadioButtons();

  var myTimer = setInterval(function () {
    moveRight();
  }, 5000);
```